# How can I mock an imported React hook/module and test that it's being called properly on different test cases using Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I need to test the following component that consumes a custom hook of mine.

```
import { useMyHook } from 'hooks/useMyHook';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const myHookObj = useMyHook();
  const handler = () => {
    myHookObj.myMethod(someValue)
  }
  return(
    <button onClick={handler}>MyButton</button>
  );
};
```

This is my test file:

```
jest.mock('hooks/useMyHook', () => {
  return {
    useMyHook: () => {
      return {
        myMethod: jest.fn(),
      };
    },
  };
});

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {

  it('calls the hook method when button is clicked', async () => {

    render(<MyComponent {...props} />);

    const button = screen.getByText('MyButton');
    userEvent.click(button);

    // Here I need to check that the `useMyHook.method`
    // was called with some `value`
    // How can I do this?

  });

});
```

I need to check that the `useMyHook.method` was called with some `value`.

I also want to test it from multiple `it` cases and it might be called with different values on each test.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to do it:

```
import { useMyHook } from 'hooks/useMyHook';

// Mock custom hook that it's used by the component

jest.mock('hooks/useMyHook', () => {
  return {
    useMyHook: jest.fn(),
  };
});

// Mock the implementation of the `myMethod` method of the hook
// that is used by the Component

const myMethod = jest.fn();
(useMyHook as ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>).mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    myMethod: myMethod,
  };
});

// Reset mock state before each test
// Note: is needs to reset the mock call count

beforeEach(() => {
  myMethod.mockReset();
});
```

Then, on the `it` clauses, I'm able to:

```
it (`does whatever`, async () => {
  expect(myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(myMethod).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(someValue);  
});
```